# Open a bootstrap modal over Leaftlet in fullscreen

Tags: leaflet, bootstrap-modal, fullscreen

I'm using Boostrap 4 and Leaflet

On Leaflet, 
I can open modal by clicking on the markers bindPopup.

In Leaflet's Fullscreen 
the modal in opened well too, 
but behind the map.

It is possible to stay in fullscreen and open the modal over the map ?

I've tried 
- to remove classname leaflet-fullscreen-on

```
$('#map').removeClass('leaflet-fullscreen-on');
```

- to change z-index of modal

  $('#modal').css('z-index',100000);

Without success

Is anyone know ?

Ps: 
Sorry for my english, I'm french (confined) ;-)

Comment: I've tried but I've can't say hello in the message.

Comment: Failing not to be able,
is it possible to exit full screen?

Comment: 'exit full screen' > when click to open modal (data-target)

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap 3 and Leaflet.fullscreen https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen I do this by calling the modal inside the map div:

```
<div id = "map" class = "map">
<? php include ("include / modal / mymodal.php"); ?>
</div>
```

The result:

• In full screen mode, the modal appears on the map,

• when disabling full screen mode, the access to the modal is blocked due to the backdrop screen, this can be annoying if the modal contains a form, links, etc. To remove the backdrop screen, you must add an argument data-backdrop="false" in the modal and add a close button to the modal:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="false">
```

Demo :  https://www.gpstraces.net/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-in-a-leaflet-full-screen-map-tutorial-1

Voili voilou

Comment: How are you handling the bootstrap modal styling being affected by inheriting the leaflet-container class?

Comment: And the modal no longer scrolling? :thinking:

Comment: @Rich : just disable the map scrolling with scrollWheelZoom: false in option